# Cache Brew builds with travis ci

Tags: macos, homebrew, travis-ci

I have a Travis CI `osx` build with a `brew` dependency that has to be built from source.

I know that Travis has the `cache` feature, but it doesn't have any documentation on how to cache `brew` builds or outputs.

Any idea on how to cache a `brew` package in travis?

Comment: Do you need to cache an existing bottle, a package/bottle that you yourself built, or brew package metadata? These are all completely different things.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**There are 3 separate, loosely related problems here:**

- **Cache downloaded bottles**
- **Cache locally-built bottles**
- **Cache Homebrew metadata**

You don't necessarily need all three, so follow whichever sections fit your needs.

---

## Cache downloaded bottles

- Add `$HOME/Library/Caches/Homebrew` to Travis' cache <sub>(actually, this path is supposed to be retrieved with `brew --cache` but you can't call it here, can you)</sub>

  ```
  cache:
    directories:
      - $HOME/Library/Caches/Homebrew
  ```
- Run `brew cleanup` at `before_cache` stage -- otherwise, the cache will grow indefinitely as new package versions are released

  ```
  before_cache:
    - brew cleanup
  ```

## Cache locally-built bottles

The [full code](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/blob/master/travis_osx_brew_cache.sh) is too long to list it here so giving the algorithm.

**This is in addition to the previous section.** If using without it, save local bottles somewhere outside of Homebrew cache at *on installing* step and add them to the cache under appropriate names at the *at startup* step below.

- **On installing:**

  - Check package's dependencies with `brew deps` recursively

    - If a bottle for the package is not available for your environment (no `(bottled)` in `brew info <pkg>` output), include build dependencies with `--include-build`
  - For each of the packages and dependencies,

    - If it's already installed (`brew list --versions <pkg>` succeeds) and latest version (absent from `brew outdated`), skip it
    - If an older version is present, in the following steps, [you'll need to install the new version alongside the old one](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/can-i-install-a-new-version-without-having-to-upgrade-runtime-dependents/4443):

      - `brew unlink` the old version if it's not keg-only (no `[keg-only]` in `brew info` output)
      - Invoke all `brew install`'s with `--force`
    - If a bottle is available, just `brew install` it
    - If a bottle is not available,

      - Build and install it [with the following sequence](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/how-are-bottle-and-postinstall-related-is-it-safe-to-run-bottle-after-postinstall/3410/4):

        ```
        brew install --build-bottle <pkg>
        brew bottle --json <pkg>
        brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies <pkg>
        brew install <bottle>
        ```

        <sub>(There doesn't seem to be any official way to get the names of the resulting bottle and JSON file. I took the bottle name from `brew bottle` output and inferred JSON file name from it.)</sub>
      - Add the bottle info into the package's formula

        ```
        brew bottle --merge --write <json file>
        ```
      - Save the bottle file into Travis cache under an appropriate name given by `brew --cache <pkg>`

        - <sub>Only do this after adding bottle info -- otherwise, you'll get a path to the source package instead.</sub>
        - <sub>(Homebrew also makes symlinks to downloaded files in `$HOME/Library/Caches/Homebrew`. You don't need to do this.)</sub>
      - Save the JSON file for later use. Make sure to add its location to Travis cache.
- **At startup:**

  - Do `brew update` if you're going to
  - Go through saved .json files. For each one, check if the local bottle is still appropriate (by comparing versions and rebuild numbers; you can parse the output of `brew info --json=v1 <pkg>` and `brew info --json=v1 <bottle>` for this data).

    - Delete the cached bottle and the .json if not

      - <sub>Since you won't be able to get the path to your bottle with `brew --cache` at this point, you need to have saved it independently. Symlinks aren't being saved in Travis' cache as of this writing, so I ended up using regular files that held the paths.</sub>
    - Re-add the bottle info into the formula like above if yes

      - <sub>There's also an unlikely possibility that they change the download URL in the formula without bumping the version -- then the bottle's expected cached name will change because the hash in it is the hash of the download URL. To allow for this, check if `brew --cache <pkg>` still points to your bottle after adding the info.</sub>
- **At `before_cache`:**

  - If you're using `brew cleanup` from the previous section, save your locally-built bottle files from cache somewhere before running it because `cleanup` may delete those that weren't needed this time around. After `cleanup`, restore those that were deleted.

## Cache Homebrew metadata

<sup>(Again, the [full code](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/blob/master/travis_osx_brew_cache.sh) is too long so giving the algorithm.)</sup>
If you run `brew update --verbose` <sub>(and make sure there are no secret variables in `.travis.yml` or your Travis project settings -- `brew` prints many status messages only if `stdout` is a tty)</sub> -- you'll see what exactly consititutes a Homebrew selfupdate operation -- thus what you should cache:

- Pulling (actually, `rebase`'ing by default) into a few paths that are actually `git` repositories:

  - `/usr/local/Homebrew` -- Homebrew itself
  - `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/*/*` -- installed taps
- Going through the taps and cache and migrating obsolete bits. Since Travis cache content is added to existing directory structure rather than replaces it, the 2nd time around, there may be strange actions and errors caused by files that were deleted as part of update, but are there again in the new VM. The ones I witnessed:

  - <sub>will always try migrating `Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask` to `Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask`, creating a copy at `Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/homebrew-cask`. If cached, this copy will cause an "error: file exists" on the next run.</sub>
  - will always try to import lots of non-committed files into `Taps/homebrew/homebrew-versions`

**So, the actions will be:**

- Add `/usr/local/Homebrew` to Travis cache

  - adding */usr/local/Cellar* and */usr/local/opt* proved to be a bad idea: first, they are too large, causing a timeout while making and uploading cache; second, this is unsafe 'cuz `postinstall` scripts may affect other arbitrary parts of the system, so one should install new package versions from (cached) bottles each time rather than cache the result. Installing a bottle only takes a few seconds anyway.
- **Before `brew update`:** clean up Homebrew codebase

  - Delete the `Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask` dir if `Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask` exists
  - Find all `git` repos under `/usr/local/Homebrew` (`find -type d -name .git`, get `dirname` of the result) and run `git clean -fxd` in each to get rid of Travis' leftovers
  - Clean up Homebrew cache from leftovers, too, with `brew cleanup` (if using in conjunction with the previous section, see there for additional operations) -- otherwise, you'll get lots of errors in `brew update` on the *"Migrating cache entries..."* stage.
- **At `brew update`:**

  - Use `brew update --merge` instead -- it will auto-resolve any possible conflicts with your local commits with bottle info
- **When re-adding local bottles** (if using in conjunction with the previous section):

  - Don't re-add bottle info into the formula if it's already present there
  - If package version has changed and your bottle info is present in the formula, remove it from the formula and `git commit` the result. There's no stock way to do that, so you'll have to parse and edit the formula file with a script and delete the corresponsing line from `bottle do` table. The path to the formula file is retrieved with `brew formula <pkg>`.
- **When installing:**

  - If using 3rd-party taps, always check if you already have that tap installed:

    ```
    brew tap | grep -qxF <tap> || brew tap <tap>
    ```

    - Since symlinks aren't saved in Travis cache, pins will likely not be remembered. But it won't hurt to check for them, too:

      ```
      brew tap --list-pinned | grep -qxF <tap> || brew tap-pin <tap>
      ```
- **At `before_cache`:**

  - Delete `Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/homebrew-cask` if it exists

Answer (score 16):

You can add brew cache directory to travis caches:

```
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

As far as I know travis doesn't support homebrew caching out of the box.

Comment: This caches Homebrew resources (the downloads), not the completed builds (binaries, etc).

Still super helpful!

Answer (score 5):

To cache the actual compiled dependencies as opposed to caching the source tarballs or ccaching object files, adding the respective packages' `Cellar` and `opt` directories to the cache and using an appropriate before_install check seems to work fine.

You could also add all of `/usr/local/Cellar/` and `/usr/local/opt/`, but that would add all installed homebrew packages instead of only the ones you need.

Example from a project that depends on openssl, libevent and check:

```
cache:
  directories:
    - /usr/local/Cellar/openssl
    - /usr/local/opt/openssl
    - /usr/local/Cellar/libevent
    - /usr/local/opt/libevent
    - /usr/local/Cellar/check
    - /usr/local/opt/check
before_install:
  - test -d /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib  || { rmdir /usr/local/opt/openssl; brew install openssl; }
  - test -d /usr/local/opt/libevent/lib || { rmdir /usr/local/opt/libevent; brew install libevent; }
  - test -d /usr/local/opt/check/lib    || { rmdir /usr/local/opt/check; brew install check; }
```

The `rmdir` is needed because TravisCI creates the cached directories if they don't exist, and `brew install` fails if `/usr/local/opt/$package` is a directory (as opposed to a symlink to a specific installed version in Cellar). For the same reason, `test` tests for a subdirectory, not the main package directory.

Note that this approach requires your own project to be able to pick up the dependencies installed in `/usr/local/opt`.

Answer (score 4):

To cache the `brew update` metadata, you [only need to cache](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/best-practice-for-homebrew-on-travis-brew-update-is-5min-to-build-time/5215/9) the `.git` folders within `/usr/local/Homebrew`

[image: successful 'brew update' cache]

Travis configuration for everyone else reading:

```
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/Library/Caches/Homebrew
    - /usr/local/Homebrew
```

```
before_cache:
  - if [ "${TRAVIS_OS_NAME}" = "osx" ]; then brew cleanup; fi
# Credit https://discourse.brew.sh/t/best-practice-for-homebrew-on-travis-brew-update-is-5min-to-build-time/5215/9
# Cache only .git files under "/usr/local/Homebrew" so "brew update" does not take 5min every build
  - if [ "${TRAVIS_OS_NAME}" = "osx" ]; then find /usr/local/Homebrew \! -regex ".+\.git.+" -delete; fi
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should cache the compiler results:

```
cache:
  ccache: true
  directories:
    - $HOME/Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

On OSX Travis currently seems not to ship ccache by default => Before using ccache the following has to be done, as well:

```
before_install: 
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ]]; then brew update        ; fi
   - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ]]; then brew install ccache; fi
```

Admittedly the completed build still is not cached. But the build results of every individual timer run that leads there are so at least big parts of the build process can count as "cached" afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew allows you to build from source:

`brew install --build-from-source [package-name]`

If you want to cache your homebrew for Travis, the only way I have seen how to do this is to create a zipped version of the homebrew dependencies you want similar to [this example](https://github.com/octoblu/gateblu-ui-build/blob/master/travis/cache-homebrew), [travis.yml](https://github.com/octoblu/gateblu-ui-build/blob/master/.travis.yml)

Comment: I don't understand how this helps with travis caching. Where did brew save to in travis? How to I save and restore the cache?